# How to set limit in html input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a form that each user have their limit of quantity they can request for through their database, but how do I set a limit to avoid requesting more than their limit in javascript.

```
Max quantity:  
<input type="number" value="<?=$user['amount']?>" name="amount" readonly/>  

Enter quantity:  
<input type="number" name="member" /> 

<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: have you tried `max="<?php $limit; ?>"` in your input? or it has to be strictly on js?

Comment: I haven't tried that, please can you explain your code?

Comment: the limit for every user comes from the database right? you can use the max attribute on your input to make sure they can't go past that
`<input type="number" name="member" max="<?=$user['amount']?>" />`

Comment: you can set a minimun amount as well like this  syntax = `<input type="number" min="min_value" max="max_value">`

Comment: I've tried that but is not working

Comment: update your question with what you tried please so we can see what the problem is, do you get some kind of error?

Comment: You would need to check this on the server side anyway - any user could manipulate what value gets send, by simply editing the field in their browser's DOM inspector.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `max` and `min` attribute to do this as given in the example below
just replace `max="5"` to `max="<?php $limit; ?>"` and do same with `min` if require

let me know if this help you out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="quantity">
        Quantity (between 1 and 5):
      </label>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```